# Must specify the --user-name option when running as root - Chrome Remote desktop

Tags: server, remote-desktop

I've installed Chrome remote desktop and Xfce on Ubuntu server 18.04 aiming at connecting with it remotely via remote desktop.When I try to execute the connection command

```
DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="xxx" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=$(hostname)
```

I'm getting `Must specify the --user-name option when running as root` in console and I don't really know what it means. Yes, I'm trying to set it up as root despite safety reasons, it's just much easier this way for me. Besides, the system is installed in container so it shouldn't be too much of a risk. Can I run it as a root? What does this message mean?

UPDATE: Well, it turned out to be more straightforward than I thought. Simply adding `--user-name=robs23` was enough :) Of course the user name needs to be the name of real user that exists within the system, so I added it and made it a member of sudo group (27). The service started and immediately failed with result `exit-code`. When I check the status of chrome-remote-service I'm getting:

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/chrome-remote-desktop@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-04-20 07:55:13 UTC; 16min ago
  Process: 24877 ExecStart=/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop --start --new-session
 Main PID: 24877 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Apr 20 07:55:12 PlexServer systemd[1]: Started Chrome Remote Desktop instance for robs23.
Apr 20 07:55:13 PlexServer systemd[1]: chrome-remote-desktop@robs23.service: Main process exited, code=exi
Apr 20 07:55:13 PlexServer systemd[1]: chrome-remote-desktop@robs23.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

The server appears on https://remotedesktop.google.com/access but it's all grayed-out, description says *Remote desktop is starting, please check in a moment*. What might be wrong?

Comment: Hello. I do not know how that message could be made any clearer. From your question. <Must specify the --user-name option when running as root>  Did you try the user name option as the message says?

Comment: @David Hi. I'm kind of new to Linux environment and still trying to wrap my head around many things.. What do you mean by user name option? Is it a parameter in this command? I see only `--name=$(hostname)`, tried to change it to `--name=robs23` but without success. Unless this name should be a name of other user that exist in the system? Or maybe I should run this command as another user?

Comment: I do not know the inner working of Chrome Remote Desktop. Maybe a Google search will help.

Comment: Well, it turned out to be more straightforward than I thought. Simply adding `--user-name=robs23` was enough :) Of course the user name needs to be the name of real user that exists within the system, so I added it and made it a member of sudo group (27). The Chrome Remote script couldn't access /root directory and exited with `ERROR:daemon_controller_delegate_linux.cc(184)] Failed to create config directory /root/.config/chrome-remote-desktop, error: FILE_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. I checked ownership of /root and it's `root:root`, so I guess it should work (if `sudo`==`root` group). Any ideas?

Comment: The `@` in `chrome-remote-desktop@.service` indicates it is a template service, you're supposed to start use it as `systemctl start/enable/restart chrome-remote-desktop@something`. What are the commands you're using to start/stop/restart this service?

Comment: @muru It's actually weird as there seem to be 2 services: `chrome-remote-desktop.service` (masked) and `chrome-remote-desktop@.service` (indirect).. And the proper should be `chrome-remote-desktop@robs23` but I don't see it in the list of all services.. I tried to start/enabled it and nothing works (don't get any messages). I've been following this process https://bytexd.com/install-chrome-remote-desktop-headless/